Black dots as nodes in a tree
I want to draw a tree like this one and the nodes should be black dots
\begin{forest}
 [[[][]][[][]]]
\end{forest}


How can I do that?

Welcome. // Please complete your posted code: it won’t compile …

Looking the code of the user @cfr here: Triangle tree with node positioning, you can define
for tree={circle, fill, inner sep=1.5pt}

The complete code is:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={circle, fill, inner sep=1.5pt}
 [ [ [ ] [ ] ] [ [ ] [ ] ] ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}



Thanks :) How can I edit the leaf nodes, for example with 1?
I tried: [ [ [ 1] [1 ] ] [ [1 ] [ 1] ] ], but then the leaf nodes are bigger then the other nodes.

You're welcome. Your request is unclear. Please clarify your problem: do you want 1 instead of the dots or  1 below the black circles? Here there are different solutions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367812/tikz-forest-number-all-lowest-level-children

Thanks, that's what I was looking for.
